# PyArrow setting column types with Table.from_pydict (schema)

Tags: pyarrow

With a PyArrow table created as `pyarrow.Table.from_pydict(d)` all columns are string types.

Creating a schema object as below [1], and using it as `pyarrow.Table.from_pydict(d, schema=s)` results in errors such as:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int
```

Is there a means to set column types in tables created from dictionaries? Context is writing to Parquet files. A similar approach in Pandas is `df.astype(schema).dtypes`.

**[1]**

```
schema = pa.schema([
  ('id', pa.int32()),
  ('message_id', pa.string()),
  ('transaction_id', pa.string()),
])
```

Comment: Do you have a reprodudcable example?
If the columns you are providing are all strings, the resulting table will have string columns, and providing a schema won't help as pyarrow expect the schema to match the given data. 

The data of the python dict array should match the type of the columns:

`pa.Table.from_pydict({"string_col": ["abc", "efg"], "int_col_as_string": ["1", "2"]})` 

vs 

`pa.Table.from_pydict({"string_col": ["abc", "efg"], "int_col_as_int": [1, 2]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach seems to be `pyarrow.Table.from_pydict(d).cast(schema)`